# Writing/Reading stream of output from external command in realtime

Tags: python-3.x, stream, subprocess, output

I was asked to run a python script in a Jenkins job, which calls external commands via `subprocess` package. In the Jenkins console, the output of the external commands should be printed in realtime or/and be writen to a log file.

I found a SO post about printing in realtime somehow like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print (line)
    if not line and p.poll() is not None:
        break
```

So I created a function for executing external commands:

```
def execute_cmd(command, splitlines=True, timeout=None, output_stream=None):

    pipe = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    utf8_output = []
    while True:
        line = pipe.stdout.readline()
        utf8_output.append(line)
        # Add to stream here
        if output_stream:
            output_stream.write(line)
        if not line and pipe.poll() is not None:
            break

    return ''.join(utf8_output)
```

As you see I didn't use print. That's because a requirement tells me to use a `stream` object which could be either streaming to a file or to output everything to the jenkins console in realtime.

So if I want to print the external output to the jenkins console, I wanted to do something like this in my job:

```
from io import TextIOBase
my_output_stream = TextIOBase()
func1(output_stream=my_output_stream)
```

Where `func1` is a function, that calls an external command via the `execute_cmd` method.
In my understanding this should write the output of the external command to `my_output_stream`

Now my question is, how can I output the data writen to that stream in realtime? Don't I need any kind of asynchronous execution? Because I can't just add a loop that reads lines of the stream after the call of `func1` as this would be executed after the execution of the function has finished, but not in realtime.

Sorry for the kind of weird description of my problem, if something is still unclear, please comment and I will update my question with further explanation.

Comment: doubt: in python 3: `if line == '' and p.poll() != None:` won't work because `line` is a `bytes` object. You should write `if not line and p.poll() is not None:` so it's portable & pythonic

Comment: Ah yes, thats true, I adjusted the examples

Comment: Did you try to pipe stdout directly into a file: `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=open('/tmp/mylog.txt', 'w'), bufsize=0)` ? I am not sure if this is really real-time (in case of buffering)

Comment: The file output doesnt have to be realtime, but the console output in Jenkins has to. So I have to get it somehow generic and write the output of subprocess into a passed stream (or maybe queue) which should be either logging to stdout of python in realtime or write to a file.

Comment: don't you need to `output_stream.flush()` as well? (since Jenkins is not a real console)